# Multi-page form with Yii in a Craft site?

Tags: form, yii

I have a Craft-based website and need to make a complex multi-'page' form on one page. The form isn't related to any Craft Entries etc, and doesn't need to save the submitted data to Craft's database (it's sent to a different database).

Having looked at a few form-related Craft plugins, I think I'll be best writing this from scratch. I'm experienced with PHP, but not Yii and I'm not quite sure how best to structure this within a page that will be generated by Craft (an Entry).

I'm guessing I could write a plugin and a variable in it is used in the Craft template to generate the form. Given that, some questions:

1. Should I create a series of [Yii forms](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-forms.html), one per 'page' of the form, and use the one indicated by a hidden 'step' form field?
2. Is there any issue with saving data to Yii sessions (for each form step's inputs) within a Craft site?
3. I could have templates for the different form 'pages' in my plugin. How would I pass data from the form (fields, submitted data, error messages) to the template?

I guess I'm also looking for general responses of either "This looks like a sensible route to explore" or "OMG don't go that way, there are monsters!" :)

EDIT: I think I should be using the plugin's [Controllers](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers) to handle form submission, passing data to templates etc. Rather than having a plugin variable in a Craft Entry's template. Maybe I can integrate Yii forms with those Controllers?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry going so far outside of Craft and using Yii's forms.

Sounds like all you need is a Craft [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction).  Use normal HTML `<form>`s from  your template and have them post to your plugin's [Controller](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers).  Each step in the form can be another [action](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#posting-to-controller-actions) on the controller.  You can persist data between form steps by saving to Craft's [HttpSessionService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpSessionService), which is just a thin wrapper for PHP's global `$_SESSION` variable.

```
craft()->httpSession->add($key, $value)
```

and:

```
craft()->httpSession->get($key)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips Brad. I thought using Yii's forms would give me the benefit of being able to use its validation, which seemed like a good idea.

Comment: You can still take advantage of validation.  Just give your plugin a [Model](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/models) and your controller can call `validate()` on it.

Comment: Ah, thanks Brad. I'll have a think. This is a large multi-step application form, and it doesn't really match up with the traditional sense of 'models' very well, but maybe I can make this work.